# okhttp3 maximum connection timeout

Tags: java, okhttp

I need help with timeouts in okhttp3. I configured the maximum connect, read and write timeout to 4 minutes like that:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                            .connectTimeout(totalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .writeTimeout(totalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .readTimeout(totalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .build();

totalSeconds = 240.000
```

but throws exception SocketTimeoutException in 2 minutes. Please someone have been in this situation? how can i solve it? Thanks in advance